# How to approach this discrete graph question about Trees.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

**A tree contains exactly one vertex of degree $d$, for each $d\in\{3, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$.**

**Every other vertex
has degrees $1$ and $2$. How many vertices have degree $1$?**

I've only tried manually drawing this tree and trying to figure it out that way, however this makes the drawing far too big to complete , I'm sure there are more efficient methods of finding the solution.

Could someone please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are $n_1$ vertices of degree $1$ and $n_2$ vertices of degree $2$.

- How many vertices are there total?
- If the graph is a tree, how many edges should it have?
- What is the sum of the degrees?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n_d$ be the number of nodes of degree $d$, and let $n$ be the total number of nodes.  Then $\sum_d n_d = n$ and $\sum_d d n_d = 2(n-1)$, so
$$\sum_d (d-2) n_d = -2,$$
equivalently,
$$n_1 = 2+\sum_{d\ge 3} (d-2) n_d.$$
Now substitute the known values $n_d=1$ for $d\in\{3,9,10,11,12\}$ and $n_d=0$ for $d >3$ otherwise, yielding
\begin{align}
n_1 &= 2+(3-2)n_3+(9-2)n_9+(10-2)n_{10}+(11-2)n_{11}+(12-2)n_{12} \\
&= 2+1+7+8+9+10 =37.
\end{align}